# Show Interstitial Ad On Button Click In WebView

Tags: android, wordpress, webview, admob, interstitial

i make apps of my Wordpress websites for android and i use WebView in my apps, i want to show Interstitial Ads in my app but when users click on Next Page Button Which is coded in my website, my next page button is like this

```
<?php next_posts_link( '<span class="nextpost"> '.__('Next', 'wp-mobile-edition').' &rsaquo;</span>' );
```

i want to show Interstitial ad when user click on next button.

how it can be ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }


    private class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            view.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
            {
                @JavascriptInterface
                public void performClick() throws Exception
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // implement your logic here for show Add
                }
            }, "login");
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but i dont have any login button

Comment: it's just a demo example to show you detect button click in webview, use your Next Page Button instead of login simple..